# TransitionEnd Event not firing?

Tags: jquery, css

I have multiple elements that are animating at a (somewhat) duration each. I'm animating using CSS3 transitions, using the jQuery library and a `transitionend` helper function from [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback).

My issue is that the `transitionEnd` event is NOT being fired! (In Chrome & Firefox)

My code:

```
var $children = $container.find('.slideblock').children();

if(Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {

    if($.browser.webkit === true) {
        $children.css('-webkit-transform-style','preserve-3d')
    }

    $children.each(function(i){
        $(this).on(whichTransitionEvent,function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $(this).show().css('animation','slideOutToRight ' + ((Math.random() / 2) + .5) + 's');
    });

}
```

**Update**

The `whichTransitionEvent` variable points to a self-executing function that returns a string containing the event name:

```
var whichTransitionEvent = (function (){
    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition'       :'transitionEnd',
      'OTransition'      :'oTransitionEnd',
      'MSTransition'     :'msTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition'    :'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition' :'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
            return transitions[t];
        }
    }
} ());

console.log(whichTransitionEvent);        // returns "webkitTransitionEvent" in Chrome
console.log(typeof whichTransitionEvent); // returns "string"
```

Comment: what's the value of `whichTransitionEvent` variable? In which browser does it work?

Comment: As it says in the question I've tested in Chrome and Firefox. Look at the link for the source of the whichTransitionEvent (it is a function that determines the transitionend event name based on the browser)

Comment: I think transitionend should Not be camelized

Comment: Did you know transitionend isn't supposed to always fire? see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16324877/261114

Comment: That's only if the transition is interrupted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attempting to replicate this in Chrome 29 and Firefox 23, your original function failed in the same way, i.e. I'm seeing `console.log(whichTransitionEvent)` returning `'transitionEnd'` for both.

Re-ordering the elements within the `transitions` hash fixes the issue, suggesting both have the unprefixed standards property as well as their own prefixed one.

Refactored function below, which fires the correct events for me:

```
function whichTransitionEvent(){
  var t;
  var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
  var transitions = {
    'WebkitTransition' :'webkitTransitionEnd',
    'MozTransition'    :'transitionend',
    'MSTransition'     :'msTransitionEnd',
    'OTransition'      :'oTransitionEnd',
    'transition'       :'transitionEnd'
  }

  for(t in transitions){
    if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
      return transitions[t];
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 20):

#### Don't confuse 'transitions' with 'animations'.

CSS animations have different callbacks.

Here's the callbacks for animation:

```
 $(document).one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", 
                "#robot", 
    function (event)
    {
        // complete
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, been scratching my head over this for a while. Good to know!

Comment: these events may be out of date now - been a long time

Comment: @Simon_Weaver These do still work. I am using the animationend and is working in Chrome. Check here for up-to-date compatibility uses - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score -1):

You are passing a function instead of a string, so you're doing the equivalent of...

```
$(this).on(function(){...}, function() {...})
```

To fix this I'd recommend setting the string at the beginning of your script, so it doesn't get called multiple times.

```
if(Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
    var transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
    if($.browser.webkit === true) {
        $children.css('-webkit-transform-style','preserve-3d')
    }

    $children.each(function(i){
        $(this).on(transitionEnd,function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $(this).show().css('animation','slideOutToRight ' + ((Math.random() / 2) + .5) + 's');
    });

}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not passing a function. I wasn't clear when I first wrote the question but I actually returned a string value to the whichTransitionEvent variable

Comment: So if you do alert(transitionEnd) what does it output?

Comment: webkitTransitionEnd in Chrome